# What is the correct network configuration for a devStack VM (virtualbox)?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox, openstack

Usually when I setup a new Ubuntu VM, i keep the `eth0` in NAT mode to get the internet & I add a `eth1` interface in `HostOnly` mode so that I can ssh.

But using this devStack guide : [Running a Cloud in a VM](http://devstack.org/guides/single-vm.html), it looks like it tried to use `eth0` as the public interface (install got stuck because `eth0` lost the network).

I know an OpenStack setup usually requires two NICs, so I'm wondering what is the correct configuration for my VM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started with the guide [Experimenting with OpenStack Essex on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS under VirtualBox](http://www.tikalk.com/alm/blog/expreimenting-openstack-essex-ubuntu-1204-lts-under-virtualbox) and here are the settings I wound up with in VirtualBox

Under Preferences > Network create a Host-only network called vboxnet0.

vboxnet0 (disable DHCP Server too)

[image: vboxnet0]

Create a new VM and go to the Network section.

The Adapters for the VM itself.
[image: Adapter 1]
[image: Adapter 2]

Network settings in the Ubuntu VM
/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#Public Interface
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet static
#address 172.16.0.1
#netmask 255.255.0.0
#network 172.16.0.0
#broadcast 172.16.255.255

# Instead of having eth1 in /etc/network/interfaces
# we create directly br100 and attach it to eth1
auto br100
iface br100 inet static
address 172.16.0.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 172.16.0.0
broadcast 172.16.255.255
    bridge_ports eth1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_fd 0
```

And in my devstack localrc / local.conf file I've included the following settings:

```
HOST_IP=172.16.0.1
FLAT_INTERFACE=br100
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=eth1
FLOATING_RANGE=172.16.0.128/25
```

This will allow to access your instances (when associated to a floating IP) from your host machine

Hope this works for you too!

Everett

Comment: Is this answer still correct?  Devstack [local.conf](http://devstack.org/configuration.html) doesn't seem to have these options anymore.

Comment: I cannot get the network interfaces file to work. Trying to bring up `eth1` results in: `Ignoring unknown interface eth1=eth1`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) installed along with virtualbox, you can start devstack using [vagrant-devstack](https://github.com/dolph/vagrant-devstack):

```
$ git clone git@github.com:dolph/vagrant-devstack.git
$ cd vagrant-devstack
$ vagrant up
```

Networking configuration is handled by the included `Vagrantfile`.