# How do I install OpenStack on a single Ubuntu 12.04 node?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstack

I'm having trouble installing OpenStack in Ubuntu 12.04, for various reasons:

- The [official Ubuntu website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure) recommends Juju and MAAS. However, this is a single node I am trying to get OpenStack installed on, and MAAS requires "two or more nodes" according to the docs. Additionally, I don't have any experience in MAAS and Juju and would rather stick to technologies I am more familiar with so that I can debug problems that arise.
- I have tried StackGeek but this fails because the node only has a single Ethernet port. The node does, however, have the second hard drive required for the nova storage.
- I have tried DevStack but cannot log into the dashboard. The login form appears fine, but as soon as I try to submit the page, my browser begins loading indefinitely.
- I have tried installing straight from packages, but I get an Internal Server Error in the dashboard upon trying to log in, with no helpful logs anywhere in sight to aid me in debugging the issue.

Each of these attempts was with a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS setup; I'm finding it really strange that no matter what I try, I cannot get OpenStack installed. Is this even a stable/mature project? Why am I encountering so many bugs?

Comment: _I have tried installing straight from packages, but I get an Internal Server Error in the dashboard upon trying to log in, with no helpful logs anywhere in sight to aid me in debugging the issue._ >>> Did you take a look at the Apache's error.log?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a pretty good experience with devstack on VirtualBox. You might want to give that a try running from the stable branches.

My VirtualBox setup is at [What is the correct network configuration for a devStack VM (virtualbox)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/409216/what-is-the-correct-network-configuration-for-a-devstack-vm-virtualbox/409331#409331)

Once you've got an Ubuntu 12.04 server VM running.

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/essex devstack/
```

Then in your devstack directory create a localrc file with the contents

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=whateveryouwant
MYSQL_PASSWORD=whateveryouwant
RABBIT_PASSWORD=whateveryouwant
SERVICE_PASSWORD=whateveryouwant
SERVICE_TOKEN=whateveryouwant

FLAT_INTERFACE=br100
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=eth1

VOLUME_BACKING_FILE_SIZE=5120M

ENABLED_SERVICES="$ENABLED_SERVICES,swift"

# For older, stable versions, look for branches named stable/[milestone].

# compute service
NOVA_BRANCH=stable/essex

# image catalog service
GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/essex

# unified auth system (manages accounts/tokens)
KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/essex

# django powered web control panel for openstack
HORIZON_BRANCH=stable/essex

# object storage
SWIFT_BRANCH=stable/essex
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2010f6
```

You can remove the Swift stuff if you don't want to install it.

Now run stack.sh